# Prepare Tree from raw data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a flat data structure like below out of which I would like to create a tree.

```
----City------------------------State --------Land Area
------------------------------------------
1--------Sitka------------- Alaska--------2,870.30
2--------Juneau----------- Alaska--------2,701.90
3--------Wrangell-----------Alaska--------2,541.50
4--------Anchorage---------Alaska--------1,704.70
5--------Jacksonville--------Florida--------747
6--------Anaconda--------------------------------736.5
7--------Butte----------------------------------------716.2
8--------Oklahoma City------------------------601.11
9--------Houston--------------------------------599.6
10-------Nashville--------------------------------527.9
11-------Phoenix--------------------------------516.7
12-------Los Angeles-----------------------468.7
13-------San Antonio--------Texas--------460.9
14-------Suffolk **----------Virginia--------400.2
15-------Buckeye--------------------------------375.3
16-------Indianapolis--------------------------------361.4
17-------Chesapeake **-----Virginia--------340.8
18-------Dallas--------------Texas--------340.5
19-------Fort Worth---------Texas--------339.8
20-------Louisville-------------------------------325.2
21-------San Diego--------------------------------325.2
22-------Memphis--------------------------------315.1
23-------Kansas City--------------------------------313.5
24-------New York City------------------------302.6
25-------Augusta--------------------------------302.5
26-------Austin----------------Texas--------297.9
```

The tree should be as below
It should Print city and Land Area
and if the State for City is present then It should show state first and then City and land area will be child for that city similar to below structure.

```
Alaska----------------9818.4
--------Anchorage--------1704.7
--------Juneau--------2701.9
--------Sitka--------2870.3
--------Wrangell--------2541.5
Florida----------------747
--------Jacksonville--------747
Texas----------------1439.1
--------Austin--------297.9
--------Dallas--------340.5
--------Fort Worth--------339.8
--------San Antonio--------460.9
Virginia Total----------------741
--------Chesapeake **--------340.8
--------Suffolk **--------400.2
Anaconda----------------736.5
Augusta----------------302.5
Buckeye----------------375.3
Butte----------------716.2
Houston----------------599.6
Indianapolis----------------361.4
Kansas City----------------313.5
Los Angeles----------------468.7
Louisville----------------325.2
Memphis----------------315.1
Nashville----------------527.9
New York City----------------302.6
Oklahoma City----------------601.11
Phoenix----------------516.7
San Diego----------------325.2
```

Please let me know how to achieve this by writing query.

Comment: Sql server reporting services to achive the desire results. sample: http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/grouping-in-ssrs-report/

Comment: Please provide schema and some sample data script.

Comment: Thanks **bvr** for the script. @Abdul Rasheed: you can get the script posted by **bvr**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @StateArea TABLE ( SNo int ,City varchar(50) ,[State] varchar(50) , area float)

insert into @StateArea values ( 1,'Sitka'  ,'Alaska', 2870.30 )
insert into @StateArea values ( 2, 'Juneau'  ,'Alaska', 2701.90) 
insert into @StateArea values ( 3, 'Wrangell' ,'Alaska', 2541.50) 
insert into @StateArea values ( 4, 'Anchorage' ,'Alaska', 1704.70) 
insert into @StateArea values ( 5, 'Jacksonville' ,'Florida', 747 )
insert into @StateArea values ( 6, 'Anaconda', NULL ,  736.5 )
insert into @StateArea values ( 7, 'Butte', NULL ,    716.2 )
insert into @StateArea values (8, 'Oklahoma City',NULL ,  601.11 )
insert into @StateArea values (9, 'Houston' ,  NULL , 599.6 )
insert into @StateArea values (10, 'Nashville', NULL ,  527.9 )
insert into @StateArea values (11, 'Phoenix' , NULL ,  516.7 )
insert into @StateArea values (12, 'Los Angeles', NULL ,  468.7) 
insert into @StateArea values (13, 'San Antonio' ,'Texas', 460.9) 
insert into @StateArea values (14, 'Suffolk **' ,'Virginia', 400.2) 
insert into @StateArea values (15, 'Buckeye' ,NULL ,375.3) 
insert into @StateArea values (16, 'Indianapolis' ,NULL ,   361.4 )
insert into @StateArea values (17, 'Chesapeake **' ,'Virginia', 340.8 )
insert into @StateArea values (18, 'Dallas'  ,'Texas', 340.5 )
insert into @StateArea values (19,  'Fort Worth' ,'Texas', 339.8) 
insert into @StateArea values (20, 'Louisville' ,NULL ,   325.2 )
insert into @StateArea values (21, 'San Diego' , NULL ,  325.2 )
insert into @StateArea values (22, 'Memphis',  NULL ,  315.1 )
insert into @StateArea values (23, 'Kansas City' ,  NULL , 313.5) 
insert into @StateArea values (24, 'New York City', NULL ,  302.6 )
insert into @StateArea values (25,'Augusta' , NULL ,  302.5 )
insert into @StateArea values (26,'Austin'  ,'Texas', 297.9)

select [State],City,area from 
(
    select isnull([State],City) as [State],null as City,sum(area) as area 
    ,case when [State] is not null then 0 else 1 end as sort from @StateArea
    group by isnull([State],City),case when [State] is not null then 0 else 1 end
    union all
    select [State] ,City,area ,case when [State] is not null then 0 else 1 end as sort
    from @StateArea
    where [State] is not null
) t
order by sort,[State],City
```

Comment: Yes, It helps. Thank you so much @bvr